# Rendering geometry through a Metal compute pipeline using SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit, metal

I am new to Metal and have the following question.

I have a simple setup to render a triangle on screen after passing the geometry through a compute pipeline. I can test the compute pipeline and render pipeline individually but am not able to get them working together. Specifically, I get a  GPU Hang error  ...

Here is my attempt to just pass through a triangle, the compute doesn't do anything except passing through the render commands like shown below

Most of this code has been adapted from [Apple's sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/indirect_command_buffers/encoding_indirect_command_buffers_on_the_gpu) The code in the sample is using a Metal View and is written in `Objective-C` The code I show is using `Swift` with `SceneKit` as the base.

I contruct a simple triangle like so,

```
// my swift variables in the ViewController
var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer!
var renderPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
let sharedLibrary = sharedMetalRenderingDevice.device.makeDefaultLibrary()!
var _icbArgumentBuffer: MTLBuffer!
var _indirectCommandBuffer: MTLIndirectCommandBuffer!
var computePipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!

// I call this inside viewDidLoad()
func setupMetalResources() {
    guard let device = sceneView.device else {
        assertionFailure()
        return
    }
    
    struct TriangleVertex {
        var position: vector_float3
    }
    
    let vertices: [TriangleVertex] = [
        TriangleVertex(position: vector_float3( 0.0, 0.5, 1)),
        TriangleVertex(position: vector_float3( -0.5, -0.5, 1)),
        TriangleVertex(position: vector_float3( 0.5, 0.5, 1))
    ]
    
    self.vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(
        bytes: vertices,
        length: MemoryLayout<TriangleVertex>.size * vertices.count,
        options: .cpuCacheModeWriteCombined)
    
    let vertexFunc = sharedLibrary.makeFunction(name: "passthrough_vertex")
    let fragmentFunc = sharedLibrary.makeFunction(name: "passthrough_fragment")
    
    let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunc
    pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunc
    
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = sceneView.colorPixelFormat
    pipelineDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = sceneView.depthPixelFormat
    pipelineDescriptor.supportIndirectCommandBuffers = true
    
    guard let pipeline = try? device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
    else {
        assertionFailure()
        return
    }
    
    self.renderPipelineState = pipeline
    
    let cullF = sharedLibrary.makeFunction(name: "testCull")
    let ag = cullF?.makeArgumentEncoder(bufferIndex: 1)
    
    let icbDesc = MTLIndirectCommandBufferDescriptor()
    icbDesc.commandTypes = .draw
    icbDesc.inheritBuffers = false
    icbDesc.maxVertexBufferBindCount = 3
    icbDesc.maxFragmentBufferBindCount = 0
    
    _indirectCommandBuffer = sharedMetalRenderingDevice.device.makeIndirectCommandBuffer(descriptor: icbDesc, maxCommandCount: 3, options: .storageModePrivate)
    
    _icbArgumentBuffer = sharedMetalRenderingDevice.device.makeBuffer(length: ag!.encodedLength, options: .storageModeShared)
    ag?.setArgumentBuffer(_icbArgumentBuffer, offset: 0)
    ag?.setIndirectCommandBuffer(_indirectCommandBuffer, index: 0)
    do {
        computePipelineState = try sharedMetalRenderingDevice.device.makeComputePipelineState(function: t!)
    } catch {
        
    }
}

// This is the SCNSceneRendererDelegate’s -> didRenderScene of SceneKit (my sceneview)
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
    guard let renderEncoder = renderer.currentRenderCommandEncoder else { return }
    let myRange: Range = 0..<65536

    let commandBuffer = renderer.commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
    let blit = commandBuffer?.makeBlitCommandEncoder()
    blit?.resetCommandsInBuffer(_indirectCommandBuffer, range: myRange)
    blit?.endEncoding()

    let computeEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    computeEncoder!.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState!)
    computeEncoder!.setBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    computeEncoder!.setBuffer(_icbArgumentBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
    computeEncoder!.useResource( _indirectCommandBuffer, usage: .write)
    computeEncoder!.dispatchThreads(MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1), threadsPerThreadgroup: MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1))
    computeEncoder!.endEncoding()

    let optimBlit = commandBuffer?.makeBlitCommandEncoder()
    optimBlit?.optimizeIndirectCommandBuffer(_indirectCommandBuffer, range: myRange)
    optimBlit?.endEncoding()

    renderEncoder.setCullMode(.back)
    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
    renderEncoder.useResource(vertexBuffer, usage: .read)
    // If I comment the entire compute encoder and pass the vertex buffer to the render encoder, it works fine
    // The below 2 lines are how I pass the vertex buffer into the render pass 
    //        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0) 
    //        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3)

    renderEncoder.executeCommandsInBuffer( _indirectCommandBuffer, range: myRange)
    //        renderEncoder.endEncoding() // uncommenting this causes "invalid usage because encoding has ended."
    commandBuffer?.commit() // I get a GPU Hang error 
    //        commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted() // uncommenting this causes the screen to go black and nothing shows  
}


// This is the Metal shader code
struct Vertex
{
    float4 position [[position]];
};
struct Vertex1
{
    float3 position;
};


vertex Vertex passthrough_vertex(const device Vertex1 *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                                 constant simd_float4x4& modelViewProjectionTransform [[buffer(1)]],
                                 uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    Vertex out;
    out.position = modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(vertices[vid].position,1);
//    out.position = float4(vertices[vid].position.x, vertices[vid].position.y, vertices[vid].position.z, 1);
    return out;
}

fragment float4 passthrough_fragment(Vertex inVertex [[stage_in]])
{
    return float4(1,0,0,1);
}

typedef struct ICBContainer
{
    command_buffer commandBuffer [[ id(0) ]];
} ICBContainer;


kernel void
testCull(uint                      objectIndex   [[ thread_position_in_grid ]],
         device Vertex1            *vertices      [[ buffer(0) ]],
         device ICBContainer       *icb_container [[ buffer(1) ]])
{
    render_command cmd(icb_container->commandBuffer, objectIndex);
    
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(vertices, 0);
    cmd.draw_primitives(primitive_type::triangle, 0, 3, 1, 1);
}
```

Could anyone point the mistake or point me in the right direction to solve this rendering issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem/question that was helped with this link:
https://gist.github.com/0xLeif/bc0d908bd7c5758d2f7766b8458ed4fd

I'm trying to make this work with my specific application, but I am a novice with metal, and still struggling to make it work with a bunch of different triangles...